# Excel VBA - loop through combinations and formula and display values that meet criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm new to excel VBA, and this is beyond my scope. I'm hoping someone can assist.

I have 3 input (user input) variables to start with (this number needs to goto Nth number).

I have a target number in another cell (user input).

I have a number of input numbers to use in a combination cell, ie: example shown below is 2, so if input is 3, then number of combinations is 3, if input N = 4, then number of combinations is 7 and so on. If this cell is 3 and number of inputs is 4, then combination would be 4 (use every number once in their own combination).

I then have a variable range cells (2 cells, user input). This is used to create further combinations with the above. Example in screenshot below should assist.

[image]

Comment: Get all source cell values into variables. Then create recursive procedure which generates all possible combinations, checks them for a condition and store into a row if matched.

Comment: Thanks Akina - I'll have to look up how to do all that tomorrow, I still have my training wheels on with VBA, so hopefully I can find something useful to help with the code.

Comment: All good folks - can’t figure it out myself, is there a way to close this post off?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1476213/edit) to show us your code and let us know exactly where your are stuck